# Is there any design reason why you can't cancel a building draft by clicking on it directly?

Tags: starcraft-2

When you issue a building command in any race, it will create a "draft" transparent model of the building that will be seen until the worker arrives at the location and the construction begins.

Once you deselect/lose track of the worker, though, there's no easy way to cancel such a building. One needs to manually locate the unit tasked with it and stop it.

Is there any design reason or implication of why the building drafts themselves aren't clickable? The only thing i can think of is that it would potentially allow modifying the action queue in the middle by cancelling a specific building - which isn't possible elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, well, sure, I'll ask it on GD.SE